# Hashing in .iso file in Python from user input; can hash string corresponding with directory, not actual file

Tags: python, hashlib

I am trying to hash an .iso file from user input. Using the open() function in Python, I can successfully hash the string corresponding to the directory of the .iso file itself, but cannot obtain a correct hash of the .iso file.

My code is as follows:

```
import hashlib

userInput = input("Path to the file: ")
isoFile = open(userInput, 'rb')
result = hashlib.sha512(userInput.encode())

print("The hash value of the file is: ")
print(result.hexdigest())
```

I have tried appending the following lines before the print() function:

```
readIso = isoFile.read()
result.update(readIso)
```

which generates a different hash, ostensibly corresponding to the actual .iso file in question.

According to `sha512sum`, the hash of the .iso file should be:

`c9b75d55fa501415ad8a1b3e597cb3c398aaf4f8c08e9219b676c07280b1d9d8cd2c6dcc6e97e077acef3d4fac4e15b021df41671b5e8f15bb557050a284e684`

When running the script with the aforementioned lines appended, the output becomes:

`28cf1c2aabc1758dafb89ed5d3e75117e255bd4101522972e30d7b4f2a4b803a979747db3c655a4f475eef8d2863dd373c5c260881c6fe067d8215641e37bc09`

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in question by doing a couple of things:

I removed `userInput.encode` from `result = hashlib.sha512(userInput.encode())`

And I appended the following loop onto my script following `isoFile = open(userInput, 'rb')`:

```
while True:
    readIso = isoFile.read(1024)

    if readIso:
        result.update(readIso)
    else:
        hexHash = result.hexdigest()
        break
```