# Getting SHA of files inside ISO with python

Tags: python, sha, iso

I have an ISO file that I'm iterating through with python's pycdlib (as described here https://clalancette.github.io/pycdlib/example-walking-iso-filesystem.html )
And I want to put each file /directory name into a list, with its SHA calculation. The sha function works on a local file but doesn't work inside the ISO.
I tried putting the exact path to each file but it shouts FileNotFoundError

I tried using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69146071/hashing-in-iso-file-in-python-from-user-input-can-hash-string-corresponding-wi), but no luck.

Any idea how to make this work?

The sha function:

```
def sha_file(filename):
 # Python program to find SHA256 hash string of a file
 # make a hash object

 h = hashlib.sha256()

 # open file for reading in binary mode
 with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
     # loop till the end of the file
     chunk = 0
     while chunk != b'':
         # read only 1024 bytes at a time
         chunk = file.read(1024)
         h.update(chunk)

 # return the hex representation of digest
 return h.hexdigest()
```

The get files function:

```
def get_all_ISO_filenames(isoFilesPath):
 iso = pycdlib.PyCdlib()
 iso.open(isoFilesPath)
 fileOrFolderObjects = []

 for dirname, dirlist, filelist in iso.walk(rr_path='/'):
     if filelist:
         for i in filelist:
            print(i)
            sha_of_file = sha_file(dirname + "/" + i)
            objectList = [i, sha_of_file, dirname]
            fileOrFolderObjects.append(objectList)

     elif dirlist:
         for j in dirlist:
             print(j)
             # sha_of_file = sha_file("/" + j)
             objectList = [j, "", dirname]
             fileOrFolderObjects.append(objectList)

    # print("Dirname:", dirname, ", Dirlist:", dirlist, ", Filelist:", filelist)

 iso.close()
 print(fileOrFolderObjects)
```

get_all_ISO_filenames(iso_path)

Comment: Your `sha_file` function obviously attempts to open a file in your actual local file system, not the ISO. You need something which fetches bytes from inside the ISO instead of the regular `open` function.

Comment: Any suggestions for that? I found a function to mount the ISO but in linux, and I need for Windows.

Comment: Surely the library you are already using has a function for retrieving the contents of member files?